# How to secure web API from unauthorized usage

Tags: node.js, api, http, encryption, authorization

Since I have done website scraping in the past myself, even for online communities, I always found it quite easy to just write some script-based tool which uses their HTTP-API and pretend to be a regular app user. I was able to do this for my mobile phone payments (log in to provider web portal, download invoices), for dating websites and some other websites, by just inspecting the HTTP traffic in the browser, then just rebuilding the HTTP requests. Long story short: it seemed to be always possible and even pretty easy to directly use whatever HTTP API I have been dealing with without using the apropriate client (website, app, ...).

Now, to the actual question. I am developing a mobile app, and along with it a HTTP-API based server component. The app allows users to register, change their profile, and also interact with each other.

What I want to achieve now is that it should be hard, or impossible, for someone to do what I just explained. That is, it should not be possible to use the HTTP API without using my app.
I know that it will most likely not be possible to 100% secure the API in a way the app cannot be bypassed. However it would be sufficient for me, if it was at least *hard enough*, so that bypassing the app would be not attractive.  How can I do this?

What I have thought of was something like this:

- use something like a RSA token generator, where the server and the app generate the same tokens
- the token shall be provided by the app in some HTTP header, and checked by the server on every request
- the generator is initialized upon user registration (leaving a tiny window of attack)
- after registration, it should not be possible for someone to intercept HTTP requests and then learn how to make the requests to bypass the app

However I havent found something like a open-source software token generator, leaving alone for Node.JS. This lead me to another idea:

I could implement some pseudo token-generator, which just works on hashing the current time together with some salt value, using e.g. MD5. The salt would be provided to the app upon registration, so it can generate the same "tokens".

Would this add some security layer? What is the best practice / proven approaches for this kind of problem?

I am no security expert, so I would appreciate any other tips or advice :)

Comment: This adds complexity which would take a dedicated reverse engineer a couple minutes more to recreate the protocol outside of the app. I don't think remote attestation is usable anywhere outside of Intel hardware and their SGX.

Comment: Okay, so, if, for example, in addition to the salt, I take e.g. the username, or a combination of username, mail, salt, time, to hash, how can this be reverse engineered? I mean of course, the attacker could brute force all combinations of user properties + salt which _could_ be used for the hash, but it doesnt sound feasable to me?

Comment: The attacker doesn't need to brute force anything. They decompile the native app or unminify the frontend JS code. Then they can just see how you build your obfuscation technique and recreate the process in their own automation framework. If it is too complex then they can just automate your app/frontend in the many UI automation tools which is much more resource intensive when it is running.